# How to use bw file to overlap the peak data?

Tags: python, bash, bioinformatics

My research field is bioinformatics.
When browsing the literature, the author provided a BW file that had already been called peak. I needed to overlay it with our peak data, but I tried many methods, such as converting the BW file into a bed file and then performing a macs2 call, but all failed. May I ask if you have a good way to solve this problem.

This is my script for bw2bed:

```
input_dir = "" #input your input dir
output_dir = "" # input your output dir
test_bw = "t" #input your input dir
threshold = 10  # Change me
bw = pyBigWig.open(input_dir+test_bw+".bw")  # Change me
of = open(output_dir+"test/"+test_bw+".bed", "w")  # Change me

for chrom, len in bw.chroms().items():
    intervals = bw.intervals(chrom)
    for interval in intervals:
        if abs(interval[2]) > threshold:
            of.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(chrom, interval[0], interval[1]))
bw.close()
of.close()
```

This is the bash script I used to call peak：

```
macs2 callpeak -t *IP*.bed -c *Input*.bed -f BED -g mm -n mESC -B -q 0.01 --nomodel --extsize 200
```

I hope to compare the data between other's peak data and mine. May I ask if you have a good way to solve this problem.

Comment: Kudos for including properly forrmatted code in your first question. ... But ... readers will need to understand what your required output looks like. A good question will have small sample inputs, required output from same inputs, code, current erroneous output and exact text of error messages. Readers should be able to copy/paste into their own environment and experience your problem. It's preferred for no external links, but given your field, links to github data may be acceptable. Good luck!

Comment: And ... this is barely a bash question, unless having `*IP*` in your cmd is causing trouble. Do I understand correctly, you would run your `mac2` once for each input, create and output for each and then compare them? We'd need to see that intermediate output also; if it is one value per line would be different to process that "all" values on one line.